# Why is there a "-fm" suffix when getting a function's name in Go?

Tags: reflection, go

For the snippet below ([runnable via the Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/mmIE8jfPY0)),

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
  "reflect"
  "runtime"
)

type User struct{}

var u = &User{}

func (_ User) DummyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {}

func funcName(i interface{}) {
  p := reflect.ValueOf(i).Pointer()
  n := runtime.FuncForPC(p).Name()
  fmt.Println(n)
}

func main() {
  funcName(u.DummyHandler)
}
```

The output is `main.(User).DummyHandler-fm`.

Why is there a `-fm` at the end of the function name?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out `u.DummyHandler` is a method value and the compiler implements methods by creating a function closure and modifying the function name. To quote Ian [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/golang-nuts/153jyb5b7p/go-nuts-fm-suffix-in-function-name-what-does-it-mean#20150318ssinqqzrmhx2ep45wjkxsa4rua):

> This seems to have become -fm on tip, by the way.
>
> Your code is getting a method value. p.beHappy is the beHappy method
>   bound to the specific value of p. That is implemented by creating a
>   function closure, and the code for that closure needs a name. The
>   compiler happens to make that name by sticking fm on the end, but it
>   could be anything that won't conflict with any other function name.
>   There isn't any way to name that function in Go, so the name is
>   irrelevant for anything other than the debugger or, as you see,
>   FuncForPC.

It seems like a better way to get a method's name is to reference the method directly, like so:

```
func main() {
  funcName((User).DummyHandler)
}
```

This will output `main.User.DummyHandler`.